# Fontspec en- and em-dash ligatures

Tags: fontspec, punctuation, ligatures

When producing en- or em-dashes with fontspec enabled i XeLaTeX, the ligatures are not produced, it simply prints `--` and `---`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine}
% \usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}

So let's try an en-dash: 32--34 wonder what that will look like? 
How about the em-dash---does it makes any difference?

\end{document}
```

Produces this result:

[image]

If in stead I load the commented `Libertine`-package instead, everything works fine and produces the following output:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: You may want to load package `libertine`. It takes care of all this stuff and provides you with other useful macros. It also sets `biolinum` as the sans font (but you can prevent that giving the option `rm`).

Comment: You probably have an old version of `fontspec`, because the last version sets `Ligatures=TeX` by default.

Comment: @Johannes_B As I wrote in my question, that is a solution, but my question was why it didn't work with `fontspec`.

Comment: `libertine` does the exact same thing internally. It tests for the engine and loads fontspec itself. Less trouble for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To enable the TeX-Shortcuts, setting the fonts should look like this:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine}
```

To your preamble.

Edit: as of TL2015, this is now the default behavior.

Comment: This does not solve the problem, but using \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine} does (as implied by @egreg in his comment to my question).

Comment: Did you add the command __before__ setting libertine as font?

Comment: My bad, you're right.

Comment: Should have mentioned it ;) I improved my answer.